# print upto second last character in unix

Tags: shell, unix

If the length of a string is 5 then how can I print upto 4th character of the string using shell scripting.I have stored the string in a variable and length in other variable.but how can i print upto length -1.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: output="string1,string2,"
length=`echo ${#output}`
Last_Char=`echo "$output" | awk '{print substr($0,length,1)}'`
actually i want to print upto string2 not upto "," Hence i want to print upto length-1

Answer (score 2):

If you are using BASH then it is fairly straight forward to remove last character:

```
s="string1,string2,"
echo "${s%?}"
```

`?` matches any single character and `%?` removes any character from right hand side.

That will output:

```
string1,string2
```

Otherwise you can use this `sed` to remove last character:

```
echo "$s" | sed 's/.$//'
string1,string2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `bash` *"parameter substitution"*:

```
string=12345
new=${string:0:$((${#string}-1))}

echo $new
1234
```

where I am saying:

```
new=${string:a:b}
```

where:

```
a=0 (meaning starting from the first character)
```

and:

```
b=${#string} i.e. the length of the string minus 1, performed in an arithmetic context, i.e. inside `$((...))`
```

Comment: output="string1,string2,"
new=${string:0:$((${#output}-1))}
echo $new   result is blank

Comment: Your variable is called `output`, not `string`, so you must use `output` where I have `string` throughout.

Answer (score 1):

```
str="something"

echo $str | cut -c1-$((${#str}-1))
```

will give result as

```
somethin
```

If you have two different variables, then you can try this also.

```
str="something"
strlen=9

echo $str | cut -c1-$((strlen-1))
```

`cut -c1-8` will print from first character to eighth.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:
When you have the string and length in vars already,

```
s="example"
slen=${#s}
```

you can use

```
printf "%.$((slen-1))s\n"  "$s"
```

As @anubhava showed, you can also have a clean solution.
So do not try

```
rev <<< "${s}" | cut -c2- | rev
```